# Jolt for deriving a new columns based on substring function ,if-else and then concatenate both the columns

Tags: json, apache-nifi, jolt

I Need help in deriving the below output using jolt .

**Input1**:

```json
[
  {
    "season": "Fall",
    "year": "2019"
  }
]
```

**Input2**:

```json
[   
  {
    "season": "Spring",
    "year": "2021"
   }
]
```

*condition for season*: If it is `Spring- Q1`,`Summer- Q2`,`Fall- Q3`,`Holiday- Q4`

*condition for year* : Need to extract last 2 characters

**Output1**:

```json
{
  "Quarter":"Q3-19"
}
```

**Output2**:

```json
{
  "Quarter":"Q1-21"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply the following transformations :

```json
[
  { // to apply the desired conditionals
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": {
        "*": "&", // to keep the other attribute("year")
        "season": {
          "Spring": { "#Q1": "&2" },
          "Summer": { "#Q2": "&2" },
          "Fall": { "#Q3": "&2" },
          "Holiday": { "#Q4": "&2" }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  { // to handle the string operations among the attributes
    "operation": "modify-overwrite-beta",
    "spec": {
      "year": "=substring(@(1,&),2,4)",
      "Quarter": "=concat(@(1,season),'-',@(1,year))"
    }
  },
  { // return "Quarter" only  
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "Qua*": "&"
    }
  }
]
```

the **demoes** on the site http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/ are :

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you please help in getting the output in array form [{"Quarter":"Q3-18"}]